# SQLAlchemy: Get only one column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get all the rows in a table, but only one column. The model looks like this:

```
class Person:
    id= db.Column(db.String(11), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
```

I want to get the `name` column ONLY but I can't find anything on how to do this.
I've tried stuff like:

```
Person.query.get(person.name)
```

The SQLAlchemy documentation doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 12):

You need to use `with_entities` to specify the column that you want to `SELECT`:

```
Person.query.with_entities(Person.name).all()
```

Comment: this doesnt work

Comment: @joehoeller it does work (hence 9 people upvoted it). Could you be more specific as to why you think it doesn't work? Also see the documentation for more info: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.with_entities

Comment: It doesn't work in sqlalchemy 2.0

Comment: @TiagoFassoni, the Query API and the `with_entities` method still exist in SQLAlchemy 2.0 (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.with_entities). If you use `select` you can use the `with_only_columns` method: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.with_only_columns.